# Combine different SVG Shapes to one shape

Tags: svg

I have an SVG file with 4818 shapes. In addition I have an Excel file that distributes every shape to another internal geographic unit. We use 66 of these units. Do you know a way/script with which we can alter and combine the shapes in the SVG file so that I got 66 shapes instead of the 4818?

My idea is to add the shapes that fall into one geo unit together and delete the "borders" within. Is there a tool the do so?

Thanks for your help
Christoph

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. You only post requirements without **showing effort** to solve the problem on your own. You are currently simply expecting us to solve the problem **for you**. Give it a try on your own, show us what you came up with - and if you get stuck along the way, feel free to come back here and ask for help.

Comment: Yes you are right, but unfortunately I am new to coding and programming and I am trying to find a tool that can perform this.

Comment: I'm afraid we don't do tool recommendations here.

Comment: Have you considered using an SVG editor such as Inkscape?  It lets you join path shapes using the Path->Union function.